# Centering text within a line css

Tags: css

I ran into a problem while designing a layout for my new website.

I want to center my text within a horizontal line, like this using CSS but found no way of doing it:

```
------- Title -------
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Vertically or horizontally? What have you tried?

Comment: we will need some of your code that you have tried to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with some simple css, I use the border bottom to create the dashed line, and an `inline-block` span element to cover over it.

http://jsfiddle.net/aqsPb/

Answer (score 1):

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/qm9mk/1/

```
/* this code is pulled from:
    https://gist.github.com/kjantzer/5436097
*/

/* creates a divider line with text
    expects <el><span>Title Here</span></el> (where el = h1, h2, etc)
*/
.divider {
    position: relative;
    color: #999;
}   
    .divider span {
        background: #fff;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .divider > span + span {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .divider.align-right {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .divider.align-right > span { padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 0;}

    .divider.align-center {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .divider.align-center > span { padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}


    /* create the dashed line */
    .divider:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        height: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    }

    .divider.dashed:before {
        border-top-style: dashed;
    }
```